# Sorting List of Lists of Strings and Integers

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Okay, so I have a list that contains multiple lists.

The list is formatted like this:

```
list1 = [["Value1",1],["Value2",3],["Value3",2]]
```

I would like to sort the inner lists by the second value so that I can, for example, print them in order, like Value1, Value3, Value2.

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using lambda:

```
>>> list1 = [["Value1",1],["Value2",3],["Value3",2]]
>>>
>>> list1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> list1
[['Value1', 1], ['Value3', 2], ['Value2', 3]]
>>>
```

Comment: People underestimate `lambda`.  It's more robust than `itemgetter`: say you want to sort by the absolute value of the first element.  Or by `x[0].lower()`, or by `int(x[0][5:])`: you're probably going to wind up using `lambda` anyway.  (On the other hand, sometimes people think `lambda` has some superpower that a function defined with `def` lacks.  Never been able to figure out why.)

Comment: @DSM yeah, so many different opinions about `lambda`, there were actually [plans](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) to even remove it in python 3000 :)

Comment: This is far more customizable than the other response. I have marked this as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted()` with an [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list1 = [["Value1",1],["Value2",3],["Value3",2]]
>>> sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(1))
[['Value1', 1], ['Value3', 2], ['Value2', 3]]
```